# Install LyX 2.3 through Cygwin on Windows

Tags: lyx, installing, windows, versions, cygwin

When I tried to open a document on my office's computer (Windows) that I had previously modified on my personal one (Ubuntu), I couldn't because the Ubuntu version of LyX was more recent (2.3.0 instead of 2.2.3).

Thus, I tried to install [LyX 2.3](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/bin/2.3.0/lyx-2.3.0-cygwin.tar.gz) on Windows [through Cygwin](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnCygwin) (for 2 hours), but I failed, because the README.txt does not explain how to execute LyX. Furthermore, the [documentation](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnCygwin) on LyX website is outdated. Indeed, I get the error

```
 ERROR: wget ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/stable/2.1.x/lyx-2.3.0.tar.xz failed
```

which shows that this procedure was suited for LyX 2.1, and has not been updated.

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to TeX.SX! I have no problem to download [through Cygwin](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/bin/2.3.0/lyx-2.3.0-cygwin.tar.gz) otherwise have you tried the [miror](http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/X11/LyX/bin/)?

Comment: My university local network blocks ftp protocol. Does yours? That could be the problem.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, I was not clear in my question. In trying to follow the steps of [the documentation](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnCygwin#toc7), the command `cygport lyxwin.cygport download` raises an error (than I've written above). Indeed, the address looked for by this command is not consistent (there is "2.1" in it instead of "2.3").
@RobtAll I have checked, and I have no problem using the ftp protocol through cygwin.